# Splitting out value from Child XElement when it exceeds in Length

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, api

I am trying to split out value from a child `XElement` when the value exceeds a set length as this is causing issue when saving the values.

So the following is an example of when the issue arises

```
<ParentNode>
     <ChildNode>This is an example value</ChildNode>
     <ChildNode />
     <ChildNode />
</ParentNode>
```

The above causes an error due to length restriction in the database

`String or binary data would be truncated.`

So to prevent this from happening I am trying to split the value from where restriction applies and put it into following child nodes like shown below:

```
<ParentNode>
    <ChildNode>This is an</ChildNode>
    <ChildNode>example value</ChildNode>
    <ChildNode />
</ParentNode>
```

So far I have following attempt at accessing the value inside the child element,
however am not sure do I split the value by creating a new `XElement`?

```
foreach (XElement childnode in xElement.Elements("ChildNode"))
{
      // Check the length of the value and if it exceeds then split it into 
      // child nodes      
      if (childnode.Value.Length > 80)
      {

      }     
}
```

Anybody lead me in the right direction please?

Comment: Do you always have empty child nodes? Or you might need to create some?

Comment: @PaulKaram I will have to create the child nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it while looping through the child nodes:

```
int maxLength = 10;
foreach (XElement childnode in xElement.Elements("ChildNode"))
{
    // Check the length of the value and if it exceeds then split it into 
    // child nodes      
    if (childnode.Value.Length > maxLength)
    {
        XElement xE = new XElement("ChildNode", childnode.Value.Substring(maxLength).Trim());
        childnode.Value = childnode.Value.Substring(0, maxLength);
        childnode.AddAfterSelf(xE);
    }
}
```

I have tried that, and after calling `Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());` this is my result:

```
<ParentNode>
  <ChildNode>This is an</ChildNode>
  <ChildNode>example v</ChildNode>
  <ChildNode>alue</ChildNode>
</ParentNode>
```

By using that way, you're directly checking the new value that you have cut from previous child and appended to the document.